# Opening a directory through php code

Tags: php, image, imagesource

I am making a page on which i have to show thumb images, which later on will show in Light Box control.

For this i have to open the images folder, to get images. I use the following code for opening directory:

```
$handle = opendir('images')
```

But this code gives lot of errors, unable to open directory.
Instead when i use this code, given below, The whole page works fine, images are shown as thumbs and also in lightbox.

```
$handle = opendir('.')
```

Please any body, tell me how can i open a folder "images" placed in the same directory as my page.

Comment: have you checked permissions?

Comment: if you are failing to to do so, then there will be some error also, so what's the error you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Try out the glob method, it automatically opens the directory handler for you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

```
$handle = glob("images/*");
```

I also recommend you do a check for the right file type to prevent loading unnecessary items (if any).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this with opendir in this way:

```
    <?php
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

As told at : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

Or you will may be interested in using scandir. That is much more simpler:

```
    <?php
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);

print_r($files1);
print_r($files2);
?>
```

As told here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php